# EJB Transaction with call to POJO

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions

Suppose I have a session bean that implements a REQUIRED transaction method:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void doTransaction() throws Exception {
    try {
        ...
        // call to non-EJB bean object (not session, stateless or entity bean)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Suppose doTransaction() changes the internal state of the non-bean object, and fails.  Does the rollback restore the original state of the non-bean?
If not, what would be the recommanded way to handle such a case? (or are POJO calls within a transaction not allowed?)

Comment: Can you give an example of this pojo, is it a static class variable? I have the feeling you are trying to do something that can be done differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rollback that EJB automatically does after e.g. an exception is thrown, will only affect resources that have joined the ongoing (JTA) transaction.

There are a couple of ways to join such a transaction. The most complete way is by implementing the [XAResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html) interface and letting your code enlist that implementation. A simpler, but less powerful way is to use a [Synchronizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/Synchronization.html).

Strictly speaking, neither the EJB container or transaction manager itself rollbacks anything. Instead, it gives the enlisted resources an opportunity to do such rollback. Thus, it will never by itself be able to restore previous values of random variables that happen to have been modified during a transaction.

For completeness, the resources that *are* typically (automatically) enlisted in a transaction are database connections (if they come from a container managed datasource), JMS messages (again, if the destination is container managed), (distributed) caches, and JCA based EIS resources.

Answer (score 0):

JavaEE won't roll back the *non-bean* changes. The only thing it will roll back are entities, but only after reading them again from the DB.

If you want that kind of semantics, you'll need to use a [Software Transactional Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) product.